# method not recognised in views in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, undefined-function

Just started learning Ruby on rails. So to pass data from the controller to the view, we use instance variables. I defined the instance variable in my controller class. Here is my controller

image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SIMo.png)

Controller:

```
def hello 
  #render('index') 
  @array = [1,2,3,4,5]
end
```

I then called the variable in the view file:

[image]

But when I run the application in the browser I get

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Please advise.

Comment: missed the controller image!! ...def hello
   #render('index')
    @array = [1,2,3,4,5]
  end

Comment: Please show us your Controller action where `@array` is set :)

Comment: Is your view called `hello.html.erb`? and in the correct place?

Comment: It is quite easy to paste in your code in Markdown-syntax, you do not have to do the image thing.

Comment: yes the view is called 'hello.html.erb'

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: it won't allow to post full stack trace

Comment: here's the start of it

Comment: 'actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'

Comment: I'm sorry about this..thanks for your time, I had the wrong action on my controller.